# Why can I not compile GTK+ using MinGW?

Tags: c++, netbeans, windows-7, mingw, gtk

Help me Stackoverflow!

So, I feel that I have set up my environment correctly but I cannot build my program!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

using namespace std;

/*
* simple gtk application
* author jan bodnar
* date february 17, 2008
*/

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

GtkWidget *window;
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 100);
gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "gtkapp");
gtk_widget_show(window);

g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",
  G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

gtk_main();

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I generated my list of include dirs from this command: pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0

Then I added the include files in the C++ compiler settings in netbeans...

My include directories:

```
../gtk/include/gtk-2.0
../gtk/lib/gtk-2.0/include
../gtk/include/atk-1.0
../gtk/include/cairo
../gtk/include/pango-1.0
../gtk/include/glib-2.0
../gtk/lib/glib-2.0/include
../gtk/include/libpng12
```

Then I generated a list of libs from this command: pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0

Then added my libs to the linker command line in netbeans with this:

`-LC:/tools/gtk/lib -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl`

But still I cannot compile a simple program!  I must be missing something stupid, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

errors:

```
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
C:\Projects\glade_netbeans3\gtk_tut/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `gtk_init_abi_check'

C:\Projects\glade_netbeans3\gtk_tut/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `gtk_window_new'

C:\Projects\glade_netbeans3\gtk_tut/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `gtk_window_get_type'

C:\Projects\glade_netbeans3\gtk_tut/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'

C:\Projects\glade_netbeans3\gtk_tut/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `gtk_window_set_position'

C:\Projects\glade_netbeans3\gtk_tut/main.cpp:28: undefined reference to `gtk_window_get_type'

C:\Projects\glade_netbeans3\gtk_tut/main.cpp:28: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'

C:\Projects\glade_netbeans3\gtk_tut/main.cpp:28: undefined reference to `gtk_window_set_default_size'

C:\Projects\glade_netbeans3\gtk_tut/main.cpp:29: undefined reference to `gtk_window_get_type'

C:\Projects\glade_netbeans3\gtk_tut/main.cpp:29: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'

C:\Projects\glade_netbeans3\gtk_tut/main.cpp:29: undefined reference to `gtk_window_set_title'

C:\Projects\glade_netbeans3\gtk_tut/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show'

C:\Projects\glade_netbeans3\gtk_tut/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `gtk_main_quit'

C:\Projects\glade_netbeans3\gtk_tut/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `g_signal_connect_data'

C:\Projects\glade_netbeans3\gtk_tut/main.cpp:35: undefined reference to `gtk_mainmake[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Projects/glade_netbeans3/gtk_tut'

'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/gtk_tut.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Projects/glade_netbeans3/gtk_tut'

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

Make file generated by Netbeans:

```
#
#  There exist several targets which are by default empty and which can be 
#  used for execution of your targets. These targets are usually executed 
#  before and after some main targets. They are: 
#
#     .build-pre:              called before 'build' target
#     .build-post:             called after 'build' target
#     .clean-pre:              called before 'clean' target
#     .clean-post:             called after 'clean' target
#     .clobber-pre:            called before 'clobber' target
#     .clobber-post:           called after 'clobber' target
#     .all-pre:                called before 'all' target
#     .all-post:               called after 'all' target
#     .help-pre:               called before 'help' target
#     .help-post:              called after 'help' target
#
#  Targets beginning with '.' are not intended to be called on their own.
#
#  Main targets can be executed directly, and they are:
#  
#     build                    build a specific configuration
#     clean                    remove built files from a configuration
#     clobber                  remove all built files
#     all                      build all configurations
#     help                     print help mesage
#  
#  Targets .build-impl, .clean-impl, .clobber-impl, .all-impl, and
#  .help-impl are implemented in nbproject/makefile-impl.mk.
#
#  Available make variables:
#
#     CND_BASEDIR                base directory for relative paths
#     CND_DISTDIR                default top distribution directory (build artifacts)
#     CND_BUILDDIR               default top build directory (object files, ...)
#     CONF                       name of current configuration
#     CND_PLATFORM_${CONF}       platform name (current configuration)
#     CND_ARTIFACT_DIR_${CONF}   directory of build artifact (current configuration)
#     CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}  name of build artifact (current configuration)
#     CND_ARTIFACT_PATH_${CONF}  path to build artifact (current configuration)
#     CND_PACKAGE_DIR_${CONF}    directory of package (current configuration)
#     CND_PACKAGE_NAME_${CONF}   name of package (current configuration)
#     CND_PACKAGE_PATH_${CONF}   path to package (current configuration)
#
# NOCDDL


# Environment 
MKDIR=mkdir
CP=cp
CCADMIN=CCadmin


# build
build: .build-post

.build-pre:
# Add your pre 'build' code here...

.build-post: .build-impl
# Add your post 'build' code here...


# clean
clean: .clean-post

.clean-pre:
# Add your pre 'clean' code here...

.clean-post: .clean-impl
# Add your post 'clean' code here...


# clobber
clobber: .clobber-post

.clobber-pre:
# Add your pre 'clobber' code here...

.clobber-post: .clobber-impl
# Add your post 'clobber' code here...


# all
all: .all-post

.all-pre:
# Add your pre 'all' code here...

.all-post: .all-impl
# Add your post 'all' code here...


# build tests
build-tests: .build-tests-post

.build-tests-pre:
# Add your pre 'build-tests' code here...

.build-tests-post: .build-tests-impl
# Add your post 'build-tests' code here...


# run tests
test: .test-post

.test-pre:
# Add your pre 'test' code here...

.test-post: .test-impl
# Add your post 'test' code here...


# help
help: .help-post

.help-pre:
# Add your pre 'help' code here...

.help-post: .help-impl
# Add your post 'help' code here...



# include project implementation makefile
include nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk

# include project make variables
include nbproject/Makefile-variables.mk
```

Comment: Netbeans is not a compiler. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Hmm.. was able to figure it out from the output. For future reference, your compiler is MinGW, not Netbeans.

Comment: Yes I know, I left that out... Sorry!

Comment: If there is nothing secret in it, maybe you can paste / upload your makefile?

Comment: Added make file generated by netbeans to original post!

Comment: g++.exe     -LC:/tools/gtk/lib -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/gtk_tut build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o

Comment: Need `nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk` and `nbproject/Makefile-variables.mk` as well.

Comment: Just a minor point, why do you use a C++ compiler for C code? (the c++ include and using namespace std is useless anyway, you're not using it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program compiles, but it does not link. The problem is that, as you have to include all directories for including all headers, you must also indicate the directories for the libraries as well. To summarize: the problem is that netbeans is unable to find the libraries to link.

In your project, go to Properties, Link, and in "Additional Library directories", you will have to mention all directories that include libraries in the Gtkmm distribution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, what I do is... Add all the header files to the C++ "Additional Include Dir's".  Then in the Linker settings put this in the "Additional Command Line" -LC:/tools/gtk/lib -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl

Comment: The lib directory is added to "Additional lib Dirs" in the linker as well as being in the PATH.  So, I don't get why it cannot link?  I also added the dirs' of all the header files to the Linker's additional lib directories, with no luck!

Comment: Ok, got it to link... shouldn't have added them to the command line, but the libs setting... I knew it would be a dumb thing!